# не работает вставка фрагмента в index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Приложение на Spring-Boot + thymeleaf.
Первым запускается файл index.html, который расположен в папке static. Остальные все шаблоны находятся в папке templates.
Я думал сделать index.html главной страницей сайта. Но пытаюсь вставить туда фрагмент шапки, используя thymeleaf, и ни чего не работает, т.е. нет этого фрагмента на этой странице.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:insert="navbar :: f-navbar"></div>
    <p>Go: <a href="/setting">Настройки</a></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

А если я перейду на страницу setting, где точно такой же фрагмент прекрасно отображается.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: То есть settings.html и index.html у вас находятся в разных папках? Если так, попробуйте ради эксперимента поместить index.html в templates, то есть туда же, где хранится settings.html.

Comment: разобрались?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во-первых:**

Файл `index.html` в папке `static` не обрабатывается `Thymeleaf`.
Это просто статический файл.
Для того, чтобы обработать данный файл как шаблон, у Вас должен быть контроллер, который обрабатывает путь `"/"` и рендерит шаблон `index.html` в папке `templates`:

```java
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {

        // some logic ...

        return "index";
    }
}
```

или же Вам нужно настроить `MVCConfig`, для обработки отдельных шаблонов напрямую.

> На самом деле данный класс может называться как угодно, главное чтобы
> он имплементировал интерфейс `WebMvcConfigurer`.
>  Хотя чаще всего
> я встречаю именно такое название
>  В дальнейшем, под `MVCConfig` я
> буду подразумевать именно класс, который имплементирует
> `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Это можно сделать добавив метод `addViewControllers` в свой `MVCConfig` если он есть

```java
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

В данном случае Вы просто указываете Спрингу какие пути можно обработать без какой-либо специальной пользовательской логики.
Для этого в Спринге есть `ViewController`, который просто принимает указанный запрос и в качестве ответа отсылает указанный отрендеренный шаблон.

Метод `addViewControllers` принимает в качестве параметра реестр.

```
    registry                     // берём данный реестр
        .addViewController("/")  // указываем путь, который мы хотим обработать
        .setViewName("index");   // указываем имя шаблона
```

**Во-вторых:**

Указывайте полный путь к шаблону с фрагментом.

**например**:

```
<div th:include="front/themes/dark/blocks::pagination"></div>
```

в моём случае файл *blocks.html* лежал по адресу *(относительно корня проекта, конечно)*

```
src/main/resources/templates/front/themes/dark/blocks.html
```

соответственно путь нужно указывать сразу после **templates**