# Spring MVC не видит view (.html)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring mvc не видит html страницу.

config

```java
public class MySpringMvcDispatcher extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

SpringConfig

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.pet")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контроллер

```
public class HomeController {

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(){
    return "home";
}
```

}

Comment: покажите контроллер

Comment: недавно отписывался в похожем вопросе... посмотрите ответ на вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216197/не-работает-вставка-фрагмента-в-index-html/1216481#1216481

Comment: если то, что там написано не поможет, то уточните что именно вы хотите от приложения, обрабатывают ли ваши контроллеры запрос "/home", или может быть вы добавили обработку шаблонов напрямую(не вижу в Вашем SpringConfig)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Здравствуйте мне нужно что бы программа при обращении по ссылке http://localhost:8080/home показывал html страницу (home.html) контроллер добавил

Comment: @azlov контроллер добавил

Comment: а где у вас шаблон лежит?

Comment: @МихаилРебров main/resources/templates/home.html

Comment: @МихаилРебров Спасибо вам большое я эту проблему только что решил на конец то

Answer (score 0):

нужно было в место

```
templateResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/");
```

писать

```
templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
```